# Help on installing Node.js on Ubuntu 10.04 from terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, installation, terminal

I was using this site to follow the commands on how to install node:

```
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation
```

This part had no errors:

```
git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/joyent/node.git # or git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git if you want to checkout a stable tag
cd node
git checkout v0.4.10 # optional.  Note that master is unstable.
export JOBS=2 # optional, sets number of parallel commands.
mkdir ~/local
```

Once I hit this command, I got the error

```
root@tgwizman:/node# ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node
Checking for program g++ or c++          : not found 
Checking for program icpc                : not found 
Checking for program c++                 : not found 
/node/wscript:228: error: could not configure a cxx compiler!
```

What should I do to get a cxx compiler?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should just be able to run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

(Also, have a read of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware for a bit more background info, etc.)

Comment: Does anyone know how to install this on Fedora 16?

I've tried this with no luck...

[agile@453D05J node-v0.10.15]$ sudo yum install g++
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
No package g++ available.
Error: Nothing to do
[agile@453D05J node-v0.10.15]$

Comment: Sorry... Typical: Found the answer, I found the answer, I need to install `$ sudo yum install gcc-c++`

Answer (score 8):

You are missing the compiler.

Just enter:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

This guide has it all.

http://www.codediesel.com/linux/installing-node-js-on-ubuntu-10-04/

Answer (score 1):

On `ubuntu` I prefer to install `nodejs` via [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), this has worked for me best and additionally it will allow you to toggle multiple version of `nodejs` which is frequently needed.

example installation:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash
command -v nvm
nvm install node
nvm use node
nvm run node --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete guide, step by step on how to setup nodejs on Ubuntu 10.04

http://blog.markmirandilla.com/2012/12/14/how-to-setup-node-js-in-ubuntu-10-04/